# Adjointness of Hom and Tensor

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products

Could someone provide me a link to the proof of the adjointness of Hom and Tensor. I did an extensive google search but could not find anything self contained that presented the proof in full generality (or at least the generality I know). 
Let $R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism, let $M,N$ be $S$-modules and $Q$ an $R$-module. Then, we have 
$$\textrm{Hom}_R(M\otimes_S N,Q) \cong \textrm{Hom}_S(M,\textrm{Hom}_R(N,Q)$$

Comment: What definition of the tensor product are you working with?

Comment: Rotman, An introduction to Homological Algebra, 2nd edition, proves it, and calls it the "adjoint isomorphism theorem".

Answer (score 14):

Let $f \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(M\otimes_S N,Q)$.  We define $g \in \operatorname{Hom}_S(M, \operatorname{Hom}_R(N,Q))$ by:

$$g(m)(n)=f(m \otimes n)$$

Similarly, if $g$ is defined, we can easily define $f$.

I'll leave it to you to prove that this map between $f$ and $g$ actually goes to the appropriate sets, but this is the basic argument. As mentioned by one of the comments, it does depend on how you define the tensor product.

Comment: Can you give me more details about how it depends of the tensor product definition? I consider that the rings are commutative.

Comment: The definitions are so different, it requires some work to prove they are equivalent. One is in terms of universal properties, the other is a complicated technical definition in terms of a quotient of a free module on the set $M\times N$ . Proving things using these definitions can be very different.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews defining the tensor product in terms of the quotient of a free module is like defining an even perfect number to be a number of the form $p+1\choose 2$ for a prime $p$ one less than a power of $2$. It's not logicaly incorrect, but it's in poor taste to call it a definition instead of a construction :-)

Comment: Not really - using generators and relations is often how we define groups. The other definitions I know use universal properties, so you need to then prove the object exists. The free group modulo a subgroup is the easiest and most direct construction to get the properties we want. @VladimirSotirov

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Using primes and their prescribed exponents is often how we define numbers too :-) More seriously, a definition in terms of generators and relations is also a definition using a universal property, namely the one resulting from combining that of a free group (or other free gadget) with that of a quotient. So good news: it turns out all definitions of the tensor product you know use universal properties.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov not clear if you are being deliberately obtuse or just accidentally. (1) we most definitely define groups in terms of quotients of free groups. We have a whole notation for it. (2) while universal properties are cool, and I like them, they are sometimes a bit much for beginners. I knew about free abelian groups, subgroups, subgroups generated by a set, and quotients long before I learned anything about universal properties and the like. I like universal properties, and think of tensor products primarily in terms of the universal property. But is it the way to teach them?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews if you're going to insult me, then I've nothing more to say to you, so I'll reiterate my points. There is only one definition of the tensor product: in terms of its universal property. The tensor product's construction as a quotient of a free module, while sometimes called a definition, is more accurately called a construction. That the result of the construction satisfies the univesal property of tensor products follows easilly from the univesal properties of free groups and quotients.